# Why In TypeScript we can re-assign an arguemts-incompatible function to another?

Tags: typescript

I came up this question with this guide https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-compatibility.html#types-of-arguments.

The example code:

```
/** Type Heirarchy */
interface Point2D { x: number; y: number; }
interface Point3D { x: number; y: number; z: number; }

/** Two sample functions */
let iTakePoint2D = (point: Point2D) => { /* do something */ }
let iTakePoint3D = (point: Point3D) => { /* do something */ }

iTakePoint3D = iTakePoint2D; // Okay : Reasonable
iTakePoint2D = iTakePoint3D; // Okay : WHAT
```

Obviously, `iTakePoint2D`'s signature is incompatible to iTakePoint3D. We will use it as `iTakePoint2D({ x: 100, y: 200 })`, then it causes a runtime error that program can't access the value of point.z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For good or ill, function parameters in TypeScript are [bivariant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) (for versions up to and including v2.5).  There's a [question in the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) which looks a lot like yours: why isn't this caught by the type system as an error?

The answer: forcing function paramaters to be [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type) (they can be wider but not narrower than the expected type) would flag this as an error, but also flag some common practices as errors where they really aren't.  And to fix those cases would require a lot of manual type assertions.  Basically some correctness is sacrificed in favor of convenience.  (you: "What?!  You can't do that!" them: "Look upon [TypeScript Design Non-Goal #3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) and despair")

There's also some discussion of the reasons in [Microsoft/TypeScript#14973](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14973) which mention compiler performance issues that arise when you start strictly enforcing parameter contravariance everyhere.

But!  Keep on the lookout for a possible [compiler flag](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654) which enforces this for standalone functions (not methods). Not sure if this will actually make it into TypeScript 2.6 or some future version, but it looks like there is work being done on this.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

EDIT: Hmm, it seems the [very document you linked](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-compatibility.html#types-of-arguments) explains it.  The bivariance makes some good things happen (see event handler code in document) and a few bad things (the code you posted).  Maybe it didn't spell that out enough?  Oh well.